# ILoggerFactory and structuremap registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my API project, Startup.cs file I have the following:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseMvc();

        loggerFactory.AddAWSProvider(Configuration.GetAWSLoggingConfigSection(),
            (logLevel, message, exception) => $"[{DateTime.UtcNow}] {logLevel}: {message}");
```

This works fine for API project. How would I register this in Structuremap Container?

```
var container = new StructureMap.Container(
                c =>
                {
                    c.For(typeof(ILogger<>)).Use(typeof(Logger<>));
                    c.For<ILoggerFactory>..../// use what?

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need to register existing instance of `loggerFactory`. There is an overload of `Use` method that takes existing instance:

```
var container = new StructureMap.Container(
    c =>
    {
        c.For(typeof(ILogger<>)).Use(typeof(Logger<>));
        c.For(typeof(ILoggerFactory)).Use(loggerFactory);
    });
```

See [Registering Existing Objects](http://structuremap.github.io/registration/existing-objects/) for some more details.

Comment: what is loggerFactory? your own implementation?

Comment: No. ASP.NET Core passes already created instance of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory`.